# How do you load extensions in sqlite built into emacs?

Tags: sqlite

I am using Emacs 30 (emacs-plus via homebrew). The documentation suggests there should be a function `sqlite-load-extension`, but there is not one. There are other sqlite commands that work, and I can create and use simple sqlite databases. I have not been able to load a sqlite extension though. `(sqlite-available-p)` returns `t`.

Via org-babel, I am able to run this code successfully (after downloading the extensions from https://github.com/asg017/sqlite-vss) [1]:

```
#+begin_src sqlite :db embeddings.sql
.load ./vector0
.load ./vss0

select vss_version();
);
#+end_src
```

But I am not able to do this using the elisp sqlite commands. Does this mean I need to rebuild Emacs somehow in a way that supports loading sqlite extensions?

[Update]

The output of this block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(let ((db (sqlite-open)))
  (sqlite-execute db "select * from pragma_compile_options()"))
#+END_SRC
```

contains `OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION`, so now I wonder how to tell which sqlite executable emacs is using, and how to change it. It is not the same as the one that org-babel uses.

[1] it is a little trick to do this on a Mac. You have to download the right library, and then grant permission in Settings to open and run them.

Comment: yes, there is SQLITE3 in system-configuration-features. The build is pretty recent (last month or so).

Comment: Check your `config.h` for these settings: `/* Define to 1 if you have the libsqlite3 library (-lsqlite). */
#define HAVE_SQLITE3 1

/* Define to 1 if sqlite3 supports loading extensions. */
#define HAVE_SQLITE3_LOAD_EXTENSION 1
` - are they both present?

Comment: It looks like it is  not compiling with sqlite3_load_extension. During ./configure I see this (checking for sqlite3_load_extension in -lsqlite3... no). I guess that it must be using a system sqlite3 that wasn't built with load extension, and not the one on my path which was. I will try to figure out how to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the system sqlite on MacOS does not support loading extensions.

It is not enough to have a sqlite installed on your path that does support loading extensions.

I solved this by running `brew link --force sqlite` and then rebuilding Emacs (`brew reinstall emacs-plus@30` worked for me).

This leads to an Emacs that has the `sqlite-load-extension` function, and it seems to be working.

But, I learned there is a hard-coded list of extensions you can load, so you can't just load any old extension, and the extension name has to match what is on the allowlist (https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/src/sqlite.c#L704). There doesn't seem to be a way to change that after compile time at this point.

[Addendum] that solution worked on a new M2 Mac. It doesn't work on an older desktop machine. For some reason brew refuses to link over the system sqlite, it seems impossible to remove it, and I haven't figured out how to make it use the one I want.

Comment: That seems worthy of a documentation update so that users who run into the same symptom will be guided to the explanation.  I would `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest that.